# regular expressions with an asterisk (with a specific example)

Tags: regex

In general, I have a hard time understand the REs.  I have been looking for good references but none has made them clear for me so far.  If anyone knows good resources, let me know.  I would really appreciate it.

I was going over a reading material on RE and there are several examples i havent been able to understand

`..(0 or 0(1 or 11)0)*..   no occurrence of 111`

I think for there to be a match, the input has to contain either `0` or `010` or `0110` or just none (sine `*` makes it optional)

The book says the following are matches `0110` `101011000010000101` `011000011` which i have no objection to because all of them contain at least either one of the three (`0` or `010` or `0110`  ).

However, the book says the following are false `1110` `1110110111` `0101011111000011`.

The book claims that `..(0 or 0(1 or 11)0)*..` means no occurrence of `111`  Can someone explain to me why that is?

Comment: The regex is saying match `0`, or match `0` followed one or two `1`s, any number of times.  This means no occurrence of `111`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen so it's either `0` or `010` or `0110` any number of times but it doesnt say anything about what happens elsewhere does it?  like wouldnt it be ok to have `0110111` or `101011000011100101`

Comment: By far the best regular expression resource is http://regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 0):

The actual regular expression for matching a binary number which has no more than two `1`s in direct sequence is:

```
^(0|(0(1|11)0))*$
```

This regex matches any number of zeroes (the first part) or any number of the following two cases: `010` or `0110`.  This means that the regex will only match a single `1` or pair `11` in the sequence.

You can explore this regex here:

## **Regex101**

Comment: @stratofortress Please mark this answer correct if it solved your problem, thanks.

Comment: the way i see it, matches will consist of the following: `0` `0110` `010`  Then, this tells me that you are not supposed to end or start with `1`.  (and you cant have `111` either).  Then how comes does the book say `101011000010000101` and `011000011` are matches

Comment: The reason they are matches is because `0`, `010`, or `0110` can be repeated any number of times (this is what the `*` operator means).  So they are matches because they consist of fragments which we know will be OK to string together.  Does this make sense?

Comment: what about the two dots on either side of the parentheses? doesnt this mean you have to have two digits on either side of `0` `010` and `0110` ?  So `01100011` is not a match because it needs two more digits in front ?  Based on your comment, it sounds like `..` and `..` front and back play no role at all so i think im still missing something

Comment: Actually, you may have found a flaw in the regex, in that it excludes any string which ends in `1` (and `011` is clearly acceptable).

Comment: to me `011` doesnt seem acceptable because the RE has two place holders on either side.  like  `_ _ (0 or 010 or 0110)* _ _`

Comment: The `..` you see are not placeholders I believe, but rather ellipsis which just means the expression can repeat.